# Recorrer campo de una columna de selección select

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Trabajo con SQL Server 2008, tengo la siguiente tabla

```
DECLARE @table1 TABLE (campo1 varchar(50))
DECLARE @rows int
INSERT INTO @table1 (campo1)
VALUES ('0.5')
    , ('1')
    , ('0.001')
    , ('1.0');

SELECT campo1
FROM @table1
```

Resultado

```
(4 row(s) affected)
campo1
--------------------------------------------------
0.5
1
0.001
1.0

(4 row(s) affected)
```

Tengo la necesidad de ir a cada valor de la columna campo1 y obtener la cantidad de caracteres que hay desde el "." hacia la derecha

Para conseguirlo estoy armando este query

```
while(select campo1 from @table1) <= @rows
begin
    -- No se como obrener el valor de campo1
end
```

Comment: ¿qué es lo que pretendes lograr con esto?

Comment: @jachguate obtener la cantidad de decimales que tiene cada elemento de campo1 uno luego con ese resultado hare lo que me respondiste en el otro hilo con este valor que obtengo poner la cantidad de decimales a un campo de nombre resultado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya que el resultado lo quieres en cada fila, no necesitas un `while` para recorrerlas. Mi recomendación es hacer el cálculo en un select, de manera que tengas el valor para cada fila dentro del mismo conjunto de resultados.

Para hacer el cálculo, puedes valerte de las funciones `charindex()`, para determinar la posición del '.' en la cadena, de `len()` para obtener la longitud de la misma y de `rtrim()` si existe el riesgo que en los datos haya una cadena que tenga espacios a la derecha. Si esto no puede ocurrir, puedes ahorrarte esa llamada.

Por ejemplo, siguiendo lo que propones en tu código:

```
DECLARE @table1 TABLE (campo1 varchar(50))
INSERT INTO @table1 (campo1)
VALUES ('0.5')
    , ('1')
    , ('0.001')
    , ('1.0');

SELECT   campo1
       , case 
           when charindex('.', Campo1) = 0 then 0 
           else len(rtrim(Campo1)) - charindex('.', Campo1) 
         end decimales
FROM @table1
```

Nos devuelve

```
campo1                                             decimales
-------------------------------------------------- -----------
0.5                                                1
1                                                  0
0.001                                              3
1.0                                                1

(4 rows affected)
```

Comment: la columna decimales que se crea a partir de un AS se puede usar para hacer el otro calculo me refiero a tomar el valor de la columna decimales para usarlo como parámetro?

Comment: Puedes hacerlo de manera sencilla con CTE o con una tabla derivada. De otra manera tendrías que repetir el cálculo cada vez que quieras utilizarla.